# Disable Command Menu Scrolling LWUIT J2me

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have a form and added four commands to it. When user click on menu option
it displays command menu (Menubar within  a dialog) which is scrollable. Having command menu 
scrollable is not user friendly for my app.

How can I disable command menu scrolling  ?

Comment: I didn't get any option to disable scrolling on menubar. Even for three commands it gives scrollable list in command menu. For touch devices , its not user friendly.

Comment: Here is the code: 
 [Created one form with some ui components and added few commands] 

  Form form = new Form("Menu test");
  // add few UI components
  ...
  ...
  
  // now add commands
  form.addCommand(CMD_BACK);
        
        form.addCommand(CMD_SEND);
        
        form.addCommand(CMD_ADD_CONTACTS);
        
        form.addCommand(CMD_RESET);
        
        
  form.addCommandListener(this);
  
 I didn't find any solution to disable scrolling on menu bar

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution... Its little tricky ( you need to Edit  MenuBar.java source file of LWUIT lib)

Add following lines in createCommandList method

```
    // Add  your menu list rendered   
    l.setRenderer(new JMenuListRenderer());
    l.setSmoothScrolling(false);
    l.setScrollVisible(false);
    // specify the height you want ( you can make it configurable as well) 
    l.setPreferredH(getCommandCount()*30); 
    l.setPreferredW(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()/2);
```

and set **menuPrefSizeBool** of your theme to true.